In a $T_1$ space, is $\dim(\bar{A})=\dim(A)$?
Let $X$ be a topological space, and recall that the Krull dimension of $X$ is the supremum of the lengths of chains of irreducible closed subsets.
Given $A\subseteq X$, one can consider the Krull dimension of $A$ under the subspace topology. It is easy to give an example where $\dim(A)<\dim(\bar{A})$. For example, consider spaces $X$ which have a generic point. Then that point has Krull dimension $0$ whereas its closure, $X$, could have any dimension.
However, I do not know an example where $\dim(A)<\dim(\bar{A})$ when the ambient space $X$ is $T_1$, i.e. all points are closed. So this begs the question

If $X$ is a $T_1$ topological space and $A\subseteq X$, then does $\dim(A)=\dim(\overline{A})$? If not, what if we add the assumption that $A$ is open?


Here is a counterexample, even assuming $A$ is open:
Let $X = (\omega + 1) \times \omega$. The topology is defined so that the closed sets are exactly,
$$\{(n \times \omega) \cup K: n \leq \omega + 1, K \subset X \text{ is finite}\}$$
$X$ is clearly $T_1$. $A = \{\omega\} \times \omega$ is open and the subspace topology on it is the cofinite topology, which has Krull dimension $1$. However, $\overline{A} = X$ has Krull dimension $\infty$ - indeed, $n \times \omega$ is irreducible closed for every $0 < n \leq \omega + 1$.
